# Hosting Microsoft BOT on Enterprise Cloud?

Tags: bots

We are trying to host the BOT on the Enterprise server IIS server which is an internet server visible to Microsoft and other outside public domains.

So, after hosting the BOT on the enterprise cloud server we would get an endpoint ex: https://myenterpriseserver.com/api/messages.

Can I use the above endpoint to register the bot in the microsoft's dev.botframework.com?

Please help, as we are planning for a large scale implementation of the BOT.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

As long as the server has a SSL Certificate it should work assuming you deploy the bot correctly. Test it out first by using the Bot Emulator to see if you can send a receive messages from a computer in your system's network. Next try registering the bot on Microsoft's [Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com) and seeing whether Microsoft's Bot Connector service can connect to the bot successfully.

Your system/intranet may block outside messages from Microsoft in which case you will have to change some settings, etc. with your firewall. [This GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3339) follows an issue with white-listing Microsoft's Bot Connector service.